# typedef error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token

Tags: c, declaration, typedef

```cpp
typedef int (*)[4] p_array;                                                                                                                               
 
int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}};
    p_array p = a;
 
    return 0;
}
```

`typedef oldTypeName newTypeName` I understand `typedef` grammar like this, so I define a new name for type `int (*)[4]` in my code, which means it's a pointer and the type pointed is an array which length is 4 and the element type in array is int. I think my code is right in logical. But it cannot be accepted by compiler. How should I understand the grammar of `typedef`.

Comment: As a side note, hiding a pointer behind a typedef is very bad practice, so you shouldn't be doing this in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin but in abstract list defnition, we can see typedef like `typedef struct {...} NODE` and `typedef NODE * PNODE`

Comment: @Lundin I will try to unify my naming style according google open-source project.

Comment: Well, if you are stuck with a coding style because it's an existing project, then stick with it of course. But don't write such code when you write new programs.

Comment: @Lundin In fact, I used java, but java naming style is very different from cpp books.

Comment: Notably, Java doesn't have pointers. It usually name types/classes with first letter caps and CamelCase. That's fine in C and C++ too, long as it is consistent. But that's a different matter from "Hungarian notation".

Comment: @Lundin I found that c++ very like using `_` when naming long var name composed by one more words. This is very rare in java.

Comment: You can ignore Lundin’s assertions about “very bad practice.” They are merely opinions.

Answer (score 2):

Defining a typedef name is similar to declaring a variable.

For example if you want to declare a pointer to array of the type int[4] you can write

```
int ( *p_array )[4];
```

or

```
int ( *p_array )[4] = a;
```

where `a` denotes an array and has the type `int[3][4]`.

So you can declare an alias for the type of such a pointer like

```
typedef int (*p_array )[4];
```

or

```
int typedef (*p_array )[4];
```

Or at first you could introduce an alias for the array type `int[4]` like

```
typedef int Array[4];
```

and then using this alias introduce an alias for pointer to such an array like

```
typedef Array *p_array;
```

Now you may write

```
p_array p;
```

or

```
p_array p = a;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef int Array[4];
Array typedef *p_array;

int main(void) 
{
    Array a[3] = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2}, {3, 3, 3, 3}};
    p_array p = a;
    
    for ( ; p != a + 3; ++p )
    {
        for ( int *q = *p; q!= *p + 4; ++q )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *q );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3
```

Comment: `typedef struct {...} struct_name ` I just inspired by like this declaration.

Comment: @MelvinLevett It is because a structure definition itself is a type name.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow - I didn't get the logic behind changing places of `typedef` and `int` in the line of `typedef int (*p_array )[4];`? Could you explain this step a bit more?

Comment: @black int and typedef the both are considered as specifiers that can follow in any order. For example to declare an alias to a constant array you may write const typedef int Array[4]; or int typedef const Array[4];

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, now I understand, thank you for your answer and the further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
typedef int (*p_array)[4];
```

Your understanding of the grammar of typedef is logical but incorrect.

The correct understanding is think of a *variable* declaration (which would be `int (*p_array)[4];` in your case) and put the keyword `typedef` in front of that. Typedef turns a variable declaration into a type declaration.